# Timer setting not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a problem with timer setting.

The code I wrote for it is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("updateTimer")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateTimer(){
        label.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: NSDate() as Date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short)
    }
}
```

I run the app, and instead of timer I get an error of type Thread.
Something like:

> "Thread 1: signal SIGBART"

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of your crash log? That might help point out the issue

Answer (score 1):

Things will work better if you replace `Selector(("updateTimer"))` with `#selector(updateTimer)`.

Then you'll be told you need to add `@objc` to your `updateTimer` function.

Unrelated but don't use `NSDate`.

Here's your fixed code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        label.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .short)
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you should keep a reference to the timer so you can invalidate it when you are done with it.

Comment: It also will be better if you hold scheduled Timer instance in a variable in order to invalidate timer when the vc deinits (to avoid Bad Access exception)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTimer(){
    label.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: NSDate() as Date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short)
}
}
```